# Handeling selections in selection enabled grids (GeneXus)

Tags: grid, smart-device, genexus

I have a grid with selection enabled. Properties:
- Show Selector: **Always**
- Selection Type: **Keep Selection while executing**

The "for each selected line" instruction saves the selected items in a database.

**Q1:**
Is it possible to automatically select these items next time the panel is opened? how?

**Q2:**
Is there any way for me to know if/when there are selected items (so I could show / hide the "accept selection" button)?

I can see a "Selection Flag" and "Selection Flag Field Specifier" properties but don't know if they can be useful for any of these questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1:
Yes.
You have to add a new variable or att or member of the SDT of the grid that will behave as the flag of the selection. This element would be boolean. If this flag is true then that means that item would be selected, false unselected. You have to load this value on your Data Provider or Load event. Remember to hide this element on the UI because you don't want it to be shown.
Then on the Grid properties you set this element as Selection Flag if it is a variable or attribute, or you put the item of the SDT that behaves as the flag in "Selection Flag Field Specifier".

Q2: I didn't find a way to do this

Comment: My grid has navigation associated, set by attributes. If i create a boolean var &selected and put it on the grid, can I create a rule like "if AttrID = 18 &selected = 1" ? Tried this on Load Event but dind't work...

Comment: If you add the &selected on the grid it doesn't work? Adding this to the events tabs has to do it: 
    Event Load
       &selected = iif(AttrID=18,true,false)
    endEvent